# How to install INim?

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I have

```
nim -v
Nim Compiler Version 0.18.0 [Linux: amd64]
```

I was trying to install [inim](https://github.com/AndreiRegiani/INim)

```
nimble install inim --verbose
Reading official package list
Downloading https://github.com/AndreiRegiani/INim using git
Cloning latest tagged version: 0.2.5
Setting Nim stdlib prefix to /home/appu/Nim
Setting Nim stdlib path to /home/appu/Nim/lib
Verifying dependencies for inim@0.2.5
Error: Couldn't find Nim version.
```

I tried

```
which nim
/home/appu/.nimble/bin/nim
```

and

```
whereis nim
nim: /usr/lib/nim /etc/nim.cfg /usr/share/nim /home/appu/bin/nim /home/appu/.nimble/bin/nim /home/appu/Nim/bin/nim
```

What should I do?